# С++. Классы. Виртуальное наследование. Проектирование классов

Tags: c++

Имеется родительский класс A, в котором объединены различные функции и другие классы, как члены данного класса (в примере это поинтер класса D). Далее я создаю класс A_Object, данный класс будут наследовать другие классы, чтобы они могли использовать функции класса A. Так как мне нужно, чтобы класс A создавался единожды (соотвественно и не повторялось создание класса D), я использую виртуальное наследование. Любые другие классы, например, B и C, уже будут наследовать класс A_Object, таким образом я единожды создаю класс A и использую его функции через наследование класса A_Object. Построение классов начинается с класса A, но почему-то вызывается его пустой конструктор (хотя насколько я понял, должен вызываться конкретно конструктор с аргументом, т.к. при создании класса B я передаю этот аргумент). Как итог программа завершает работу неправильно. Скорее всего, я изначально неправильно проектирую построение классов. Поэтому прошу помочь либо с корректировкой моего примера либо с проектировкой нового.

````
/*
result:

    init B
    A()
    A_Object(std::string auth): auth-token
    D(std::string auth):
    B(std::string auth): auth-token
    D::print():
    init C
    A()
    A_Object()
    C()
    D::print():
    test.exe (процесс 9168) завершил работу с кодом -1073741819.
*/

class D
{
    std::string m_auth;

public:
    D(std::string auth) :
        m_auth(auth)
    {
        std::cout << "D(std::string auth): " << auth << std::endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "D::print(): " << m_auth << std::endl;
    }
};

class A
{
    D* m_class_d;
    std::string m_auth;

public:
    A() :
        m_class_d(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }

    A(std::string auth) :
        m_class_d(nullptr),
        m_auth(auth)
    {
        std::cout << "A(std::string auth): " << auth << std::endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        delete m_class_d;
    }

    void create()
    {
        m_class_d = new D(m_auth);
    }

    D* get_class_d()
    {
        return m_class_d;
    }

    std::string get_auth()
    {
        return m_auth;
    }
};

class A_Object : virtual public A
{
public: 
    A_Object()
    {
        std::cout << "A_Object()" << std::endl;
    }

    A_Object(std::string auth) :
        A(auth)
    {
        std::cout << "A_Object(std::string auth): " << auth << std::endl;
        create();
    }
};

class B : public A_Object
{
public:
    B(std::string auth) :
        A_Object(auth)
    {
        std::cout << "B(std::string auth): " << auth << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A_Object
{
public:
    C()
    {
        std::cout << "C()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "init B" << std::endl;
    B b("auth-token");
    b.get_class_d()->print();

    std::cout << "init C" << std::endl;
    C c;
    c.get_class_d()->print();

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Не стоит дважды копировать строку; не стоит использовать голые указатели (нет `delete`)

Comment: [Грабли 2: Виртуальное наследование](https://habr.com/ru/post/185826/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы было понятней, давайте упростим код:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()        
    {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const std::string& auth) 
    {
        std::cout << "A(std::string auth): "<< std::endl;
    }   
};
class A_Object : virtual public A
{
public:
    A_Object() 
    {
        std::cout << "A_Object()" << std::endl;
    }
    A_Object(const std::string& auth) :
        A(auth)
    {
        std::cout << "A_Object(std::string auth): " << auth << std::endl;        
    }
};

class B : public A_Object
{
public:
    B(const std::string& auth) :
        A_Object(auth)
    {
        std::cout << "B(std::string auth): " << auth << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Для  `A_Object a` будет вызываться конструктор по умолчанию базового класса,  до конструирования объекта . Результат:

```
A()
A_Object()
```

Для  `B b("auth-token")` Будет вызываться в первую очередь конструктор  базового класса, на чем строится     объект `b`, а значит конструктор `A()`.  Что выводит на экран:

```
A()
```

Так как в списке инициализатора конструктора целевого объекта  нет этого конструктора, а есть только конструктор `A_Object`, который в свою очередь вызвал бы конструктор своего базового класса, если бы  он не был виртуальным, а с учетом виртуальности, у него уже есть базовый объект, который создан конструктором класса `B`  а значит будет выведен только:

```
A_Object(std::string auth): auth-token
B(std::string auth): auth-token
```

Для того,  чтобы объект целевого производного класса строился на объекте виртуального класса, созданным посредством вызова  нужного конструктора, нужно в инициализаторе целевого класса, указать явно:

```
B::B(const std::string& auth) : A(auth),
    A_Object(auth) {... }
```

Тогда и получите результат с вызовом конструктора виртуального базового класса `А` с аргументом.